# How to make a simple 5 line JavaScript Multiplication table for loop

Tags: javascript

I am currently struggling on this project, as I have no idea what goes where and through the various searches online, I get different answers so the code I have currently have most likely is no where near correct. The multiplication table goes 1 - 10 and shows multiplication answers up to 5. (1x1 = 1, 1x2 = 2, all the way up to 5x10, if that makes sense) I need a correct example of my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Multiplication Tables</title>
</head>
<body>
 <p>Enter a number below to see its multiplication table.</p>
 <input type="text" name="txtNumber" id="txtNumber" placeholder="Enter a number" />
 <br />
 <br />
 
 <button onclick="DisplayTable();">Click Me</button>
 <div id="multiTable"></div>
 
<script language="javascript">
function DisplayTable(){
 for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
  for (var i = 1, var j = 0; (i+j) <= 10; i++, j += i) {
     System.out.print("\t"+i*j);
  System.out.println(); 
}
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Given the context I assume this is JavaScript, so the java or basic tag doesn't belong, and there isn't a `System.out.print` in JavaScript, and you're accidentally re-using the same loop counter variable

Comment: Perhaps you could type out the correct format?

Comment: It's not just a formatting issue - you appear to be attempting to use parts of the Java standard library to output in JavaScript which doesn't make any sense - what you need to do is use the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) to output the table

Comment: <div id="mt"></div><script>var div = document.getElementById("mt"); div.innerHTML = "Java and Javascript are completely different.";</script>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) When inserting/including Javascript, please use `type="text/javascript"` instead of `language="javascript"`, because the latter is not standard code.

2) As already mentioned in the comments, you're trying to redefine the counter of your first for-loop (`var i = 1`) in your second for-loop (`var i = 1, var j = 0`). It's better to use the `i` counter for the outer `for`-loop and only `j` for the inner/second `for`-loop. (Since the `i` counter is already available in both loops, and you don't want to reset it there.)

3) `System.out.print` and `System.out.printLn` are not JavaScript functions. Javascript's equivalent is `document.write("Some text");`. But this function is NOT recommended, since it will clear all HTML when you call it after the page is loaded (which is the case here).
So, instead, in your Javascript function, use a string variable where you store your generated HTML-code. Then let your Javascript function add a new table row/cell on every iteration in your `for`-loop.

4) When creating a table in HTML, don't use `\t`, instead use the appropriate `<table>` tag, with table rows (`<tr>`) and table cells (`<td>`).

5) It's unclear what you want to do with just the one `input`-field. I guessed you want to use `input`'s to let the user choose where to start and end with the multiplications (rows and columns). In that case, you need 4 `input`-fields (with unique ID's). These 4 values are fetched at the start of your Javascript function to use them as start and end points for your `for`-loops.

Example:

```js
function DisplayTable(){
  /* first, get the values of the input fields and parse them as integers */
  var colStart = parseInt(document.getElementById("startCol").value);
  var colEnd = parseInt(document.getElementById("endCol").value);
  var rowStart = parseInt(document.getElementById("startRow").value);
  var rowEnd = parseInt(document.getElementById("endRow").value);
  
  /* create a buffer variable for the new html code & put a opening table tag in it (with a border for clearity) */
  var htmlBuffer = "<table border='1'>";
  
  for (var i = rowStart; i <= rowEnd; i++){
    /* add a opening table row tag to the buffer */
    htmlBuffer += "<tr>";
    
    for (var j = colStart; j <= colEnd; j++) {
      /* add a table cell with the multiplication inside it to the buffer */
      htmlBuffer += "<td>"+ (i*j) + "</td>";
    }
    
    /* add a closing table row tag to the buffer */
    htmlBuffer += "</tr>";
  }
  
  /* add a closing table tag to the buffer */
  htmlBuffer += "</table>";
  
  /* print/put generated html code inside the DIV element */
  document.getElementById("multiTable").innerHTML = htmlBuffer;
}
```

```html
<p>Fill in the numbers below and click "Generate table" to see their multiplication table.</p>
    Start columns with:<br />
 <input type="text" name="startCol" id="startCol" placeholder="Enter a number" value="1" /><br />
    End columns with:<br />
 <input type="text" name="endCol" id="endCol" placeholder="Enter a number" value="20" /><br />

    <br />

    Start rows with:<br />
 <input type="text" name="startRow" id="startRow" placeholder="Enter a number" value="1" /><br />
    End rows with:<br />
 <input type="text" name="endRow" id="endRow" placeholder="Enter a number" value="10" /><br />

    <br />
 <br />
 
 <button onclick="DisplayTable();">Generate table</button>
    <br />
 <div id="multiTable"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for spending the time to answer that question. I know i included the html part, but what im focusing on is the javascript part, since its a javascript class. Also, there is all that information but the instructor gave a hint to say that the javascript part would only be 5 lines. Im just looking for the most basic option. Thanks again for answering!

Comment: I probably put too much options in the script, but you can remove those options that you don't need. For example some inputs if you already know up till which row (or column) you have to create the table.
Also, the code might be a little extensive, but in this way it's more clear what I wrote. You can compress it ofcourse (or use a minifier to make it all into one line :) )
But most important: just try it out, Google the functions and read the documentation (for example on W3Schools), as it is a class.. Good luck!